Renaming a SQL Server table using Fluent API in .NET Core
I am working on a console application in order to practice my skills. I've connected to my SQL Server database, created the tables and seeded the data using code first approach.
Now I am trying to use Fluent API in order to do some things. I am stuck at the first thing, and that is renaming a table (current name: Users, new name I want it to be AppUsers).
Here is my code:
//main method
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    ServiceCollection myServiceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    ConfigureServiceCollection(myServiceCollection);
    var myServiceCollectionBuilder = myServiceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

    // this code is used to debug a migration.
    using(var scope = myServiceCollectionBuilder.CreateScope())
    {
        var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        var migration = context.GetService<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.IMigrator>();
        migration.Migrate("RenameUsersTable");
    }

    // var userRepository = myServiceCollectionBuilder.GetRequiredService<IAsyncRepository<User>>();
    // var users = await userRepository.GetAllAsync();
}

// register dbcontext in the DI container
public static void ConfigureServiceCollection(ServiceCollection myServiceCollection)
{
    // register ApplicationdbContext.
    myServiceCollection.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext>(provider => {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
        options.UseSqlServer("ConnectionString");
        return new ApplicationDbContext(options.Options);
    });

    // register the base repository
    myServiceCollection.AddScoped(typeof(IAsyncRepository<>), typeof(BaseRepository<>));
}

This is what my DbContext looks like. In the OnModelCreating I am trying to rename my table:
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Order>? Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderItem>? OrderItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product>? Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Profile>? Profiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User>? Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("AppUsers");
    }
}

// This is used by EF Core so that it knows how to use `DbContext` at design time.
public class DesignTimeDbCreation : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext> contextBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
        contextBuilder.UseSqlServer("MyConnectionstring");

        return new ApplicationDbContext(contextBuilder.Options);
    }
}

This is the generated migration file:
public partial class RenameUsersTable : Migration
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Orders_Users_UserId",
                table: "Orders");

            migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey(
                name: "PK_Users",
                table: "Users");

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "OrderItems",
                keyColumn: "OrderItemId",
                keyValue: 1);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "OrderItems",
                keyColumn: "OrderItemId",
                keyValue: 2);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "OrderItems",
                keyColumn: "OrderItemId",
                keyValue: 3);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "OrderItems",
                keyColumn: "OrderItemId",
                keyValue: 4);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "OrderItems",
                keyColumn: "OrderItemId",
                keyValue: 5);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "OrderItems",
                keyColumn: "OrderItemId",
                keyValue: 6);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "OrderItems",
                keyColumn: "OrderItemId",
                keyValue: 7);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "OrderItems",
                keyColumn: "OrderItemId",
                keyValue: 8);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "OrderItems",
                keyColumn: "OrderItemId",
                keyValue: 9);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "OrderItems",
                keyColumn: "OrderItemId",
                keyValue: 10);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "OrderItems",
                keyColumn: "OrderItemId",
                keyValue: 11);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "OrderItems",
                keyColumn: "OrderItemId",
                keyValue: 12);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "OrderItems",
                keyColumn: "OrderItemId",
                keyValue: 13);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "OrderItems",
                keyColumn: "OrderItemId",
                keyValue: 14);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "OrderItems",
                keyColumn: "OrderItemId",
                keyValue: 15);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "Orders",
                keyColumn: "OrderId",
                keyValue: 1);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "Orders",
                keyColumn: "OrderId",
                keyValue: 2);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "Orders",
                keyColumn: "OrderId",
                keyValue: 3);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "Orders",
                keyColumn: "OrderId",
                keyValue: 4);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "Products",
                keyColumn: "ProductId",
                keyValue: 1);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "Products",
                keyColumn: "ProductId",
                keyValue: 2);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "Products",
                keyColumn: "ProductId",
                keyValue: 3);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "Products",
                keyColumn: "ProductId",
                keyValue: 4);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "Products",
                keyColumn: "ProductId",
                keyValue: 5);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "Profiles",
                keyColumn: "ProfileId",
                keyValue: 1);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "Profiles",
                keyColumn: "ProfileId",
                keyValue: 2);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "Profiles",
                keyColumn: "ProfileId",
                keyValue: 3);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "Users",
                keyColumn: "UserId",
                keyValue: 1);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "Users",
                keyColumn: "UserId",
                keyValue: 2);

            migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "Users",
                keyColumn: "UserId",
                keyValue: 3);

            migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
                name: "Users",
                newName: "AppUsers");

            migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey(
                name: "PK_AppUsers",
                table: "AppUsers",
                column: "UserId");

            migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Orders_AppUsers_UserId",
                table: "Orders",
                column: "UserId",
                principalTable: "AppUsers",
                principalColumn: "UserId",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Orders_AppUsers_UserId",
                table: "Orders");

            migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey(
                name: "PK_AppUsers",
                table: "AppUsers");

            migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
                name: "AppUsers",
                newName: "Users");

            migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey(
                name: "PK_Users",
                table: "Users",
                column: "UserId");

            migrationBuilder.InsertData(
                table: "OrderItems",
                columns: new[] { "OrderItemId", "OrderId", "ProductId" },
                values: new object[,]
                {
                    { 1, 1, 1 },
                    { 2, 2, 2 },
                    { 3, 3, 3 },
                    { 4, 4, 4 },
                    { 5, 1, 5 },
                    { 6, 2, 1 },
                    { 7, 3, 2 },
                    { 8, 4, 3 },
                    { 9, 1, 4 },
                    { 10, 2, 5 },
                    { 11, 3, 1 },
                    { 12, 4, 2 },
                    { 13, 1, 3 },
                    { 14, 2, 4 },
                    { 15, 3, 5 }
                });

            migrationBuilder.InsertData(
                table: "Products",
                columns: new[] { "ProductId", "Price", "ProductName" },
                values: new object[,]
                {
                    { 1, 7.99m, "Apa" },
                    { 2, 10.99m, "Lapte" },
                    { 3, 17.99m, "Suc" },
                    { 4, 12.99m, "Bere" },
                    { 5, 57.99m, "Gin" }
                });

            migrationBuilder.InsertData(
                table: "Profiles",
                columns: new[] { "ProfileId", "FirstName", "LastName", "UserId" },
                values: new object[,]
                {
                    { 1, "Mihai", "Raducu", 1 },
                    { 2, "Dana", "Arvinti", 2 },
                    { 3, "Irina", "Raducu", 3 }
                });

            migrationBuilder.InsertData(
                table: "Users",
                columns: new[] { "UserId", "Email", "UserName" },
                values: new object[,]
                {
                    { 1, "mihai@example.com", "Mihai" },
                    { 2, "dana@example.com", "Dana" },
                    { 3, "irina@example.com", "Irina" }
                });

            migrationBuilder.InsertData(
                table: "Orders",
                columns: new[] { "OrderId", "OrderDate", "UserId" },
                values: new object[,]
                {
                    { 1, new DateTime(2024, 11, 6, 15, 9, 18, 180, DateTimeKind.Local).AddTicks(7420), 1 },
                    { 2, new DateTime(2024, 11, 6, 14, 54, 18, 180, DateTimeKind.Local).AddTicks(7460), 2 },
                    { 3, new DateTime(2024, 11, 6, 13, 39, 18, 180, DateTimeKind.Local).AddTicks(7460), 3 },
                    { 4, new DateTime(2024, 11, 6, 13, 29, 18, 180, DateTimeKind.Local).AddTicks(7460), 1 }
                });

            migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Orders_Users_UserId",
                table: "Orders",
                column: "UserId",
                principalTable: "Users",
                principalColumn: "UserId",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        }
    }

This is the error message I get:
Applying migration '20241123112634_RenameUsersTable'.


System.InvalidOperationException: There is no entity type mapped to the table 'Users' which is used in a data operation. Either add the corresponding entity type to the model, or specify the column types in the data operation.
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.GetPropertyMappings(String[] names, String tableName, String schema, IModel model)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.GenerateModificationCommands(DeleteDataOperation operation, IModel model)+MoveNext()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(DeleteDataOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator.<>n__1(DeleteDataOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass35_0.b__0(MigrationCommandListBuilder b)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator.GenerateExecWhenIdempotent(MigrationCommandListBuilder builder, Action1 generate) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(DeleteDataOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.<>c.<.cctor>b__82_29(MigrationsSqlGenerator g, MigrationOperation o, IModel m, MigrationCommandListBuilder b) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(MigrationOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(MigrationOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(IReadOnlyList1 operations, IModel model, MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions options)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(IReadOnlyList`1 operations, IModel model, MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions options)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.GenerateUpSql(Migration migration, MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions options)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.<>c__DisplayClass16_2.b__2()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
There is no entity type mapped to the table 'Users' which is used in a data operation. Either add the corresponding entity type to the model, or specify the column types in the data operation.

What I've tried:

running the project (dotnet run)
creating a new migration (dotnet ef migrations add RenameUsersTable) and then updating the database
Debugging the migration process

If you think it is relevant I can post the generated migration files (RenameUsersTable.cs and RenameUsersTable.Designer.cs).

The designation "my sql db" is somewhat confusing as there exists a database named MySQL, but you seem to be using SQL Server.

Right. I am using sql server

Please post the Up method of the generated RenameUsersTable.cs. Since this table seems to be heavily referenced by FKs in other tables, renaming is not a trivial task (all FKs have to be dropped first and recreated after rename).

@IvanStoev I posted the Up and Down methods. Thanks!

Looks like you have model seeding (.HasData(...)) in some previous migration (all these DeleteData commands in Up and InsertData in Down). And the problem seems to be with the DeleteData from the table being renamed. Since everything in the code you've  shown looks ok, most probably you are hitting some EF Core bug, so better post it on their GitHub issue tracker.
